# Is there a direct shortcut to mute/unmute breakpoints in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I think we can customize the shortcut in Keymap, but is there a shortcut provided by Intellij itself? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts are not assigned to these actions by default. You can change it in `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` settings:

[image]